# Is there a way to graphically show that a solution is the minimum or stationary solution to a functional?

Tags: graphing-functions, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, visualization

I'm looking for the functional analogue to the visual representations of function optimization you most commonly see.

To illustrate, if we have some function:
$$
f(x) = (x-1)^2+1
$$

We can look at the problem graphically, and we can immediately find the minimum by visual inspection, and we see that it is at $x=1$

[image: Fig. 1]

Now, lets say we have a functional:
$$
J[x]=\int^t_0 \mathcal{L}\left(x(\tau),D({x})(\tau),D^{2}({x})(\tau),...,D^{n}({x})(\tau),\tau\right)\,\text{d}\tau
$$

Such that the solution (one way or another) to the first variation of this functional yields the first order representation of the harmonic oscillator:

$$
\dot{x}(t)=y(t),\dot{y}(t)=-x(t),x(0)=x_0,y(0)=y_0
$$

Is there some way for me to visualize the functional in  $(x,y,J)$ space, such that I can obviously see that there is some "valley" in the visual of the functional that admits the trajectory of the harmonic oscillator, something like:

[image: Fig. 2]

Here, there is a circular valley inside of which a certain solution to the harmonic oscillator equations could fit.

So, instead of visually inspecting a single variable function and seeing where it attains a minimum, we can visually see that the functional attains a minimum along this trajectory.

One such example is plotting the contours of the Hamiltonian function, the resulting contours each relate directly to a trajectory which minimizes or makes the associated functional stationary.

The phase space plot for the contours of the Hamiltonian of a pendulum results in:

[image: Fig. 3]

Although not all functionals can be framed in such a way, this is because of the special characteristics of Hamiltonian systems. Maybe there is some other way to generate similar visualizations for other functions? Some phase space representations of solutions based on the functional?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to visualize. How do you plot something over the space of all smooth functions?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if this is possible, that's why I asked the question. My thinking was that, if I evaluate the functional along a trajectory that does not make it stationary, it will be larger over the interval of interest. This corresponds to a larger scalar value for the functional for some function input. Now, if I can somehow relate this evaluation of the functional at this trajectory  to locations in phase space, then I'd be able to visualize it (possibly?). It might be possible in the frequency domain, if I'm dealing with linear systems. I'll try to come up with an example.

Comment: An example is plotting the contours of the Hamiltonian function, the resulting contours each relate directly to a trajectory which minimized or makes the associated functional stationary. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: Why on earth did you guys close the question? What the OP is asking is very clear. Now directed to Ron, visualizing over the space of functions means visualizing over an infinite dimensional space, you'd need a lot of additional constraints before a natural visual technique becomes apparent. An idea worth pursuing is perhaps looking at finite approximations (ex: 5 terms of a Taylor series) and then "visually" inspecting which finite approximations were locally optimal

Comment: Then take a greedy approach, where it is assumed those are the 5 terms to your approximation, now what should terms 6,7,8,9, etc... be. A rigorous derivation of why this works, or closely approximates the optimal solution is beyond me at the moment but it could be doable with some analysis

Comment: @frogeyedpeas So, would such a plot be over the Taylor series coefficients?